# Communication with WCF service in a different domain

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service hosted on a windows service by TCP protocol.
The service works well when the consumption from another machine in the same domino, but now I need it consumed from a machine that is not in the domain, when connecting I generate authentication problems, the state reading about the subject and more or less I understand that it's time to generate some certificates ....
But you cannot generate the certificates, nor make the corresponding configuration on the back as in the client to be able to make the consumption.
The truth can not generate the files, if possible help with some help on how to generate these certificates and configure the service.

In this link a description of the creation of the certificates is made:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/wcf-message-security-using-certificates/

But at the time of generating the certificates it fails:

[image]

I appreciate your help with my concerns.

Client service mode:

```
        <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding
            name="NetTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"
            transferMode="Streamed"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://xxx.xxx.x.x:520/TcpBackService" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"
          contract="ServicioCopiado.IServicioCopiadoEnvio" name="NetTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="xxxx\xxx" />
          <dns />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Back service model:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default"/>
    <services>
      <service name="ServicioCopiadoEnvio.ServicioCopiadoEnvio" behaviorConfiguration="BackEndServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:520/TcpBackService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ServicioCopiadoEnvio.IServicioCopiadoEnvio" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                 openTimeout="00:02:00"
                 receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
                 sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BackEndServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In different domain environments, there are different DNS servers, meaning that addressing needs to cross routes. Nettcpbinding only works in the same intranet environment. For service scenarios on the Internet, I recommend using wshttpbinding.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-system-provided-bindings
If it is a friend domain, on the basis of ensuring the network is smooth and trusting each other, we can use the message security mode (Nettcpbiniding default security mode) and use windows credentials to ensure message security.
As for authentication with a certificate, the hyperlink is too old, please attempt the Powershell to create the self-signed certificate.

> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "Currenthostname"
>   -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"

Link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps
The certificate should be configured on the server-side. Please refer to the below code snippet.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApp3.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ConsoleApp3.ITestService" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:16666"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then we are able to consume the service with client proxy class by using Adding service reference.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.